# Duplicate ajax call issue for two different jquery events

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on inline edit of html elements using ajax and jQuery. Everything is working fine except one problem. The issue is the ajax call is running duplicated on two different jQuery events viz. "change" and "keydown". Here's my to the point code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'selector', function(){
    $.ajax({
        // ajax code goes here...
    }); 
})

$('selector').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13)
    { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            // ajax code goes here...
        }); 
    }
})
```

The duplicate ajax call issue doesn't arise when the "change" event is occurred. It's only seen when the "keydown" event is fired. When some value is changed in the textbox and enter key is pressed the ajax code is being called and update the field. But as soon as we click anywhere on the page the same ajax call is again run. How can we fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

Selector used in two snippets of code is same and its a `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: If your `selector` is `input` then it's working perfectly

Comment: is the selector a class also does it refer to button or textbox?

Comment: @Manoj, its an input type box.

Comment: @MacferAnn, I updated my question, please provide me some solution.

Comment: can u mention at what scenarios u need to call AJAX coz the below answer could solve for an autocomplete i.e calls every time the text is typed or pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this [code example](https://jsfiddle.net/goran90/2j1h9qrc/2/) should solve the problem.

It basically uses only one event - the `keyup` one and by storing the original value of the input it could simulate the `change` event that you want too.

`keyup` is the better option here because it has the new value of the input element.

Comment: I saw that but would it not call ajax every time you write in the box and not only when you finish typing? That's not wise!

Comment: That's why I wasn't sure that I am getting the question correctly. Can you please elaborate on why do you need the `change` event and when do you want to invoke the ajax request with this event?

Comment: plz come on chat room otherwise a lot of comments will void STO policy

Comment: Actually what we need to do is - there is a textbox. Typing in this box to update the value will fire `change` event when it loses its focus. Another option to update the value is with Enter key which fires `keydown` event. Both events calls same ajax request. But issue is when we press Enter key the ajax is being called but the `change` event is automatically gets fired when the user clicks anywhere on the page since textbox loses its focus. So in short we want to fix this duplicate ajax call if the value is already being updated. I guess its fairly good description.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the change event because you're not using it properly. All you need is `blur`.

[Check out here](https://jsfiddle.net/goran90/pc9urqqu/10/).